# Using kendo-angular messages along with ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, ngx-translate, kendo-angular-ui

I have an angular 5 app using kendo charts. 
I have used ngx-translate for I18N support.
Question is, how do i translate messages in kendo components?

I installed the npm package: @progress/kendo-angular-messages. 
What is the step to set the language for kendo components, so that locale specific resource files get loaded from "@progress/kendo-angular-messages" package?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the [updating-messages-dynamically](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/localization/messages/#toc-updating-messages-dynamically) topic. We are using a simliar solution to get the correct messages from ngx-translate's  `TranslateService`.

Comment: @ Philipp: Thanks. I don't want to change any kendo messages. Instead i want to use the messages provided by kendo for different locales. How can i do that? Is there a way i can set locale code for kendo?

Comment: @Philipp did you solved it?